# Dynamically change REST connector Source

Tags: node.js, rest, qliksense

I am developing an application to track performance metrics being pulled from a REST service, but I need to dynamically change the data being visualized based on user input. Is there a way I can automate the data being loaded into qlik sense?

I am new to qlik sense, so it might just be I cannot find the right documentation on this, even just a link could be helpful.

Comment: Silly question but do you have the possible values that can be used as an input?

Comment: @StefanStoichev So its just a dataset, probably JSON, and I want to be able to make GET calls to the data interface, then send that data to Qlik Sense. Keep the same charts, but populate them with different data.

Comment: in general QS is an "offline" tool. You load all the data and then filter (slice) the data in the UI. If you need new data - reload the app to get it. So if you know the possible values that need to be extracted - loop them in the script, get the data and then provide the iteration values (as a field) on which the users will filter the dashboard (one or many).

Comment: If you dont know the values then the story get more complicated. QS provide excellent api and you can build an app (nodejs, c#) that can generate applications based on the user input (web form/site), load the data and display the dashboard (as a template)

Comment: Also there is something called `Direct Discovery` which might be in help (but im avoiding using it if possible) https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/April2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/DirectDiscovery/access-large-data-sets-with-direct-discovery.htm

Comment: @StefanStoichev so there is no way I can send new data to the same REST connector, unless I were to manually change the URL/Query parameters?

Comment: There is no way I know of to force a data reload based on a user action.  You haveto get all of the data in your app at load time and then do the selections. When you load data you include in the table(s) a source designation (i.e. "Source1", "Source2", etc.) and then put that source designation in filter pane.  Alternatively you can build logic in the visualization that selects the right source.  HTH.